# Change imported values by values in user-supplied file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a package called **pgk1**. It's **__init__.py** contains

```
from defaults.py import *
```

**defaults.py** contains definiton of scalars, lists, dictionaries, i.e.

```
CONSTANT = "C1"
SPECIAL_DIRS = {"OPT_DIR1": "/path/to/dir1", "OPT_DIR2": "/path/to/dir2"}`
```

and **main.py** contains

```
import pkg1
print pkg1.SPECIAL_DIRS["OPT_DIR1"]
```

I would like the user to be able overwrite some or all of the default constant values by supling a python **user.py** file in the form

```
SPECIAL_DIRS["OPT_DIR2"] = "/path/somewhere/else"
```

My question is, how to dynamically overwrite the values from **defaults.py** by values from **user.py** so they can be acccesed as the package constants, i.e.

```
print pkg1.SPECIAL_DIRS["OPT_DIR2"]
```

would yield

```
/path/somewhere/else
```

File **defaults.py** could contain any basic python type and user might  want to modify only one key in already existing dict.

I can prepare **user.py** in the form

```
import pkg1
pkg1.SPECIAL_DIRS["OPT_DIR2"] = "/path/somewhere/else"
```

And than import it in **main.py** and will get the desired results.

But I wonder if there is a better solution that importing a file in the middle of other code.

Comment: Why do you need to import *in the middle of other code*? And if you do, remember that the imported file is only executed once, no matter how many times it is imported.

Comment: I don't need to import anything, just change overwrite the default values. Importing is the only way I figured out and that is the reason I asked this question.